# What is wrong with my jquery code?

Tags: jquery

I have this div:

```
<div class="transparency" data-title="<? echo $perf; ?>">&nbsp;</div>
```

An this is the jquery code which extracts the data-title value and replaces the &nbsp with it.

```
function performerNames(){

    var performername = $(".transparency").data('title'); 

    var divcontent = $(".transparency").innerHTML;

    if (divcontent == '&nbsp;'){

        $(".transparency").html(''+divcontent+''); 

    }

}
```

Ty very much!

Comment: Have you actually called `performerNames()` somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `html()` instead of `innerHTML`::

```
var divcontent = $(".transparency").html();
```

and you want to replace by data, so:

```
$(".transparency").html(''+performername+'');
```

instead of:

```
$(".transparency").html(''+divcontent+'');
```

### UPDATE:

whole code:

```
function performerNames(){    
    var performername = $(".transparency").data('title');     
    var divcontent = $(".transparency").html();    
    if (divcontent == '&nbsp;'){    
        $(".transparency").html(''+performername+'');     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The innerHTML should not ever be `&nbsp;` unless you double entity encoded your non-brekaing space. Thus the body of your if block does not execute.

**EDIT:**
This, as suggested by others, works for me:

```
function performerNames()
{
    var $transparency = $( '.transparency' ),
        performername = $transparency.data( 'title' );

    if( $transparency.html() == '&nbsp;' )
    {
        $transparency.html( performername );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, I guess the `.html()` would return an empty string on that, right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  As others here mentioned, it should return the `&nbsp;`. In my edit you can see code that works for me as suggested by others. If it didn't return the `&nbsp;` it should return the actual non-breaking space char which that entity represents.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(".transparency").innerHTML;` with `$(".transparency").html();`

Answer (score 0):

You're just setting the html content to be the same as it is:

```
var divcontent = $(".trasparency").html();
$(".transparency").html(divcontent);
```

Which should be

```
$(".transparency").html(performername);
```